# Nginx non HTTPS websites redirect to other HTTPS websites

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm using nginx for hosting multiple websites on a ubuntu server. Basically my setup is as follows.

My first domain `example1.com` (SSL enabled) can be accessed from `http://example1.com` as well as from `https://example1.com`. **This working fine.**

But my 2nd domain `example2.com`, I don't have SSL enabled - but when I type `https://example2.com` the url redirects to the first domain `https://example1.com` - **Which is wrong**

Now currently I have added this server block if someone type in the URL with `https://` it will redirect back to `http://` on the `same domain`. But this is not the right way to handle this issue. Does anyone has some better ideas?

```
server {
  listen   443 ssl;
  server_name  example2.com www.example2.com;
  rewrite ^   http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you’re only using a single IP address (server-side) and rely on the [TLS Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension (client-side). Nginx will always use your default HTTPS server if nothing else is available to handle the request.

Your solution looks quite right to me, although it will produce an error on the client-side if you have no valid certificate. The only other possibility would be to create a default invalid HTTPS server that simply drops the connection attempt. But I guess that’s not what you want.

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example2.com *.example2.com;
    return      301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Always use `return` if you redirect at such a point.

A default invalid catch all configuration could look like the following:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         _;
    ssl_certificate     blank.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key blank.key;
    return              403;
}
```

As I said, it will simply drop any connection attempt that doesn't contain a valid HTTP Host in the submitted headers or if the submitted HTTP Host in the header is not valid.

Comment: Added a sample blank catch all configuration; but I guess you don't need nor want that.

Comment: As long as it doesn't break anything, I don't mind trying the second approach with blank cert :) - Thanks for your time @fleshgrinder

Comment: For an extremely in-depth discussion about security and nginx have a look at https://calomel.org/nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

Having the following will listen on 443 (SSL), and because you don't have a SSL certificate for this domain, nginx will use the first or default SSL certificate, which will throw invalid domain error. Simply remove it, so that it doesn't listen on 443 (SSL).

```
server {
  listen   443 ssl;
  server_name  example2.com www.example2.com;
  rewrite ^   http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Well I'm using this block to redirect any https request to http. If I don't use this block any request comes to example2.com goes to example1.com